# Access Symfony2 session from another php file?

Tags: session, symfony

I want to access symfony session data from another php page, based in web directory.

I've defined:

```
$this->getRequest()->getSession()->set('school', 'abc');
```

And want to get('school') in another php paged existed in web directory (not a controller). I've searched Google for hours and tried lots of alternatives but couldn't be success.

Comment: Do you need to get Symfony2 session from a plain php script?

Comment: Just `var_dump` the `$_SESSION` and see what's in there. I guess symfony2 adds some namespace to it's session variables!

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this problem with this solution:

In config.yml:

```
framework:
    session:
        save_path: ~
```

Then I started a `session_start();` in a plain php script.

And accessed via:

```
$_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['my_value'];
```

Now, it's ok.

Comment: Is it possible to do the reverse elegantly? I know I can use `$_SESSION['my_var']` in symfony to get non-symfony session vars, but was wonderng if there's a way using symfony's session object. I've looked, but I don't see a way.