# How to access to the Symfony2 session from anywhere?

Tags: php, session, symfony

I did my own URLGenerator (Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator) extending the original URLGenerator. I want to access the Symfony2 session from there, but I can't.

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator as BaseUrlGenerator;

class UrlGenerator extends BaseUrlGenerator
{
protected function doGenerate($variables, $defaults, $requirements, $tokens, $parameters, $name, $referenceType, $hostTokens)
{
    $url=parent::doGenerate($variables, $defaults, $requirements, $tokens, $parameters, $name, $referenceType, $hostTokens);

   **//Here I want to access to session** 

    return $url;
}

}
```

I read the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) but I dont know how to acess. Only can access to session from a controller? 
I searched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789538/access-symfony2-session-from-another-php-file), but I want to invoke a Symfony Object to the session.

\Resoruces\config\services.yml

```
 parameters:
    router.options.generator_base_class: Ex\Bundle\ExBundle\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I added:

```
ex.service:
    class: Ex\Bundle\ExBundle\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator
    arguments: [@session]
```

and:

```
private $session;

public function __construct($session, RouteCollection $routes, RequestContext $context, LoggerInterface $logger = null)
{
    $this->routes = $routes;
    $this->context = $context;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->session = $session;
}

protected function doGenerate($variables, $defaults, $requirements, $tokens, $parameters, $name, $referenceType, $hostTokens)
{

 $url=parent::doGenerate($variables, $defaults, $requirements, $tokens, $parameters,   $name, $referenceType, $hostTokens);

 $this->session->set($url,$url);

 return $url;
}
```

** ERROR here on ->set (: Call to a member function set() on a non-object in )

Comment: You can extend the constructor to accept a SessionInterface object and inject the `@session` service there; did you try this?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the part where you register your url generator?

Comment: Did you see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901536/how-to-properly-override-the-default-router It tells you how can you use the container in your class, and you can use that to fetch the `session` service.

Answer (score 0):

As Maerlyn said maybe you should use a construct to implement this.
Have a look on how to use arguments in service: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

**Update 1 :** Check the second answer. It could be helpful [How do you access a users session from a service in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192916/how-do-you-access-a-users-session-from-a-service-in-symfony2)

**Update 2 :**

For me this code works but Idon't know if my override of Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator is a good practice.

app/config/config.yml

```
ex.service:
  class: Test\YourBundle\Service\UrlGenerator
  arguments: [@router]
  calls:
       - [setSession, ["@session"]]
```

src/Test/YourBundle/Service/UrlGenerator.php

```
namespace Test\YourBundle\Service;
use \Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator as BaseUrlGenerator;
use \Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext as RequestContext;
class UrlGenerator extends BaseUrlGenerator {

    private $session;

    public function __construct(\Symfony\Component\Routing\Router $routes,  \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger = null) {
        parent::__construct($routes->getRouteCollection(), new RequestContext(), $logger);
    }

    public function setSession($session) {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function getSession() {
        return $this->session;
    }


    protected function doGenerate($variables, $defaults, $requirements, $tokens, $parameters, $name, $referenceType, $hostTokens)
    {
     $url=parent::doGenerate($variables, $defaults, $requirements, $tokens, $parameters,   $name, $referenceType, $hostTokens);

     $this->session->set($url,$url);

     return $url;
    }
}
```

src/Test/YourBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

```
class DefaultController {
    // ...
    public function indexAction()
    {
            // Retrieve my service
            $service = $this->get('ex.service');
            echo $service->generate('_demo');
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: But I can only access in a controller, isn't it?

Comment: Symfony 2 provide a container (which contains services). You can list them by using the command line : php app/console container:debug. In the second link (second answer) you have an example.

Comment: After do that, I get this: "FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function set() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\src\Ex\Bundle\ExBundle\Routing\Generator\Urlgenerator.php line 42" when I call it to  $this->session->set('ex','ex');

Comment: is Urlgenerator a service? and did you inject the session to that service?

Comment: Where are you getting other parameters in the __construct() ? I tried the code whitout doGenerate() method and the object Session is correctly retrieve. Maybe owing to the protected method / inheritance class ? I don't know.

Comment: @Debflav could you show me the code that you tried?

Comment: I let you manage the inheritance from UrlGenerator because I make a dirty code =). I've discover another way. You can add a setter in your service : calls: - [setSession, ["@session"]]

Comment: @Debflav Thank you for your work, but the same error (Call to a member...) I only want to save in session all urls. When someone generates a Url to save that URL in session

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;`

$session = new Session();
$session->get('variable');
```